# Running Sequence of program in android Activity

Tags: android, bluetooth

```
package com.example.led_control;

import java.util.Set;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;


import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private BluetoothAdapter adapter;
private Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices;
private BluetoothDevice device;
static int flag=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    if (adapter == null) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is not supported",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    } 
    else 
    {
        if (adapter.isEnabled())
        {

        }
        else 
        {
            Intent turnBTon = new Intent(
                    BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(turnBTon, 1);
        }
    }
    setRequiredDevice();
}


private void setRequiredDevice() {
    pairedDevices = adapter.getBondedDevices();
    for(BluetoothDevice d : pairedDevices)
    {
        if(d.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("HC-06"))
            {
              device = d;
              flag=1;
              break;
            }
    }
    if(flag==0)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Required Device is not paired",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UI.class);
        intent.putExtra("address", device.getAddress());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
}
```

My question is that:  i'm running this code on emulator which doesn't support bluetooth. So this activity should finish in the first condition

```
if(adapter == null)
```

because of call to finish() method inside the if block.But when i ran it i got NullPointerException on line calling to setRequiredDevice() method.

I can't understand how the code reached to that line while it should have finished in the if block because emulator doesn't support bluetooth.

But if i remove the line setRquiredDevice() then the activity finishes showing the Toast message.
anyone please explain.

Comment: `if (adapter == null) ` is not explaining the exception. Use try catch for exception raised and do the settings accordingly

Comment: If block is not throwing exception but it is not working since adapter is already null in case of emulator....So i think if block must execute till finish and execution must not reach the line setRequiredDevice() to throw exception.....@MurtazaKhursheedHussain